# Возврат id после вставки. MySql

Tags: java, mysql, select, insert

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать возврат id записи которая была вставлена при помощи INSERT. 
Как вариант можно делать ещё один запрос после вставки но это не очень.

Я пишу на Java-е.

Comment: Покажите как у Вас организована вставка, через SQL-statement или еще что?

Comment: "*это не очень*" - а всему миру вполне "очень" :-) Ну, если не хочется явно выбирать last_insert_id, то есть `getGeneratedKeys()`.

Comment: @carapuz использую PreparedStatement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
stmt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
rs.next();
return rs.getInt(1);
```

Comment: Булевская переменная, нужно ли возвращать id. Убрал, чтобы не смущала

Comment: `rs.getInt(1);` почему именно `1`? а не `"id"`?

Comment: Потому что он принимает int, а не string в качестве параметра. Вернее можно и String, но рекомендуется именно индекс столбца. http://www.javaportal.ru/java/tutorial/tutorialJDBC/resultset.html

Comment: Спасибо. помог.